# How can I use independent instances of one class, its methods and variables encapsulated in several threads/tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

There is a datatable showing the name of different algorithms and the underlying=symbol that has to be traded:

> ID - Symbol - AlgoName
>
> 1. EURUSD Azur
> 2. USDCAD Azur
> 3. EURUSD Blue
> 4. GBPUSD Blue

Each algorithm represented by its name (Azur or Blue) shall be a different class. The alorithms=classes imply a variety of variables, lists and methods to calculate their trading signals.

The "strategy" ID=1 uses the algorithm "Azur" on EURUSD and the strategy with ID=2 uses the algorithm "Azur" on USDJPY. Each algorithm represented by its AlgoID is unique which means it uses own data stored in list and values in its variables. Each Algorithm has a method `Start()` which receives a unique variety of parameters and calls one furhter method to import historical price date and store in several lists.

After the start sequence each strategy will be addressed by a `RealTimePrice` event which calls a further method inside the algorithm class: `public void OnTickUpdate()`. this method needs to use separately the values of variables and lists as they have been generated "strategy-wise" before.

How would you approach such a task?

Comment: The task is less than clear.

Comment: Look at ThreadLocal class if you want each Thread to have its own object instance

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, was my very first question - I will improve

Comment: @ Dmitry: Thank you, seems to be exactly what I need.